# Allocate any mutable object with immutable class or vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, allocation, nsmutablestring

This may sound pretty strange to some people.. but I just went on to ask this.. 
Obviously, no one wants to do it.. but just to make the concept clearer, I want to ask.
Usually we do it like this:

```
NSString *myString=[[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *myString=[NSString string];
```

As far as I understand, it gives a pointer object of `NSString` class, but, what if I do it like this:

```
NSString *myString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSString *myString=[NSMutableString string];
```

If this happens, what kind of class does "string" actually belong.. and since I have initialized it with a mutable class, can **I send messages of NSMutableString class to "myString", which is an object of NSString class**  ?? Whatever the case is can I know what is the concept behind this.. also, this can be in the case of arrays, dictionaries and even many other calsses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The type of your object will be the one used by the alloc method.
If you allocated with NSMutableString, then your object will be a member of NSMutableString class.

```
NSString *myString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

What's going on it's you have a pointer for the allocated object with the type of it's parent class, so the compiler will not see methods of NSMutableString and will get a warning if you try to call them directly.

But again, your object it's still a member of NSMutableString class, and it will respond to messages of NSMutableString class.

Even though you declared myString as a pointer to a NSString, you can perform this test the see what I'm talking:

```
BOOL test = [myString isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]]; //this will hold true
```

You can even perform a cast to do a method call explicit.

```
NSString *myString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[(NSMutableString*)myString someNSMutableStringSpecificMethod];
```

PS: this counts not only for mutable / immutable objects, but for all specialization classes

Answer (score 0):

What happens on the second line is you get a `NSMutableString` object, but the reference is an `NSString`, you can only call messages on the reference's exposed interface, therefore the messages would be send to your `NSMutableString` object, BUT only the interface exposed by `NSString` would be visible.

You can however at any time cast it to a `NSMutableString` for example:

```
[((NSMutableString *)myString) appendString:@"anotherString"] // This works because of the cast

[myString appendString:@"anotherString"] // Compiler complains because it does not find that method in NSString interface.
```

and send messages exposed by `NSMutableString` interface.